# iOS App Drawer (like Google Maps App)

Tags: ios, navigation-drawer

I'm making a simple menu drawer for my app and I am curious if it's better to do a `CGAffineTransform` translation on the `mainView` to show the drawer, or if I can just change the `mainView.frame.origin.x`? Something tells me I'm sure that one is better for performance than the other.

Can anybody point me to which one I should be using?

Comment: I would also love to know!